# Contact Quick Edit, refreshParent after CRM.api3('CustomValue', 'create)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Stuck with jQuery, which intercepts a contact Quick Edit and updates a custom field. All is fine and a value gets updated in the database but is not immediately shown, need to click "Edit" again to see it changed.
Have been searching high and low here https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ajax/#crmrefreshparent and in the code for "refreshParent" to no avail. Any pointer in the right direction please?

```
CRM.$(function ($) {
$(document).on('crmFormSuccess', function (e, data) {
    var changedElement = $(this);
    console.log(changedElement);
    if (typeof (data) == 'object') {
        // data.status: success|| form_error
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            const userContext = data.userContext.split('=');
            const cid = userContext[userContext.length - 1];
            CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
                "return": ["custom_1", "custom_2"],
                "id": cid
            }).then(function (result) {
                    CRM.api3('CustomValue', 'create', {
                        "entity_id": result.id,
                        "custom_2": result.values[result.id].custom_1 == "1"?   "1" : "0"
                    }).then(function (result) {
                       // Please, refreshParent, if you can! 
                        }, function (error) {
                        // oops
                    });
            }, function (error) {
                // oops
            });
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
$('.crm-custom-set-block-5 .crm-summary-block').load(CRM.url('civicrm/ajax/inline', {
  cid: '133', 
  class_name: 'CRM_Contact_Page_Inline_CustomData', 
  groupID: '5', 
  customRecId: '1', 
  cgcount: '1',
  reset: 1,
  snippet: 5,
  type: 'page'
}), function() {
  $(this).trigger('crmLoad');
});
```

replace

1. cid to contact_id
2. groupId with custom group Id
3. .crm-custom-set-block-5, replace 5 with custom group id

Comment: in my case it is 'form.CRM_Contact_Form_Inline_CustomData' and unfortunately it is not being triggered.

Comment: does the custom set is on Summary tab or on its own tab?

Comment: is on Summary tab and its equivalent of $el would be e.target.childNodes[3] (which is a div with "crm-container-snippet") class - assuming the result of .crmSnippet(); on the element.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I'd say this sends the investigation into the whole new direction. It works! Would you please point me to documentation regarding the solution and  data-edit-params usage ( if exists )? Cheers.

Comment: where you want to use data-edit-params?

Comment: I was curious where this solution comes from and realized I've seen all the params inside the form "data-edit-params".  Would be nice to read more about how this works, not sure if this piece is documented though.